# Mod_rewrite-like feature in IIS ( 5/6/7 )?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6, iis-5

I'm working on (surprise) a web framework that entirely is dependent on mod_rewrite, however I'd like for it to be compatible with IIS ( if possible ). There's a slight slight chance one of the sites being built will have to be stored on an IIS box, I'm wondering if there's any rewrite module in the most popular versions of IIS I could rely on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS7 is easy--use the URL rewrite module as Garethm points out.

IIS<7 is a bit trickier--no integrated pipeline to latch on to. Presuming you can require that persons hosting on IIS have dedicated hosting, or can at least get an ISAPI module installed, check out iconic's [Isapi Rewrite](http://www.codeplex.com/IIRF) Filter. It is free, open source and pretty much mimic's mod-rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

For IIS7, there is the IIS [URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/extensions/URLRewrite). If I remember correctly, you can install it with the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/server.aspx).

There also appears to be a company that has rewritten a rewriting module for IIS that is compatible with Apache's mod_rewrite configuration format. You can find out about it on the [Micronovea](http://www.micronovae.com/ModRewrite/ModRewrite.html) website. I have no experience with this one though.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [HeliconTech's ISAPI_Rewite](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) with great success. It's not free or open source but it's reasonably cheap and well supported, also super-easy to install and get running.

Answer (score 0):

Helicon also have a 'lite' version that is free.